# Master Theorem: Why is T(n)=16T(n/4)+n! considered Θ(n!)

Tags: master-theorem

I am having some problem trying to understand why

T(n)=16T(n/4)+n!

is considered

Θ(n!)

I am using the following master theorem below from here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/advanced-master-theorem-for-divide-and-conquer-recurrences/

[image]

**The confusing part here is that my friend says that the answer is actually O(n!) and not Θ(n!)... So I am really confused.**

Comment: It should be `Thetha(n!)` if I am not wrong! Try using the theorem 4.1 stated in page 94 of  [CLRS](https://mcdtu.files.wordpress.com/2017/03/introduction-to-algorithms-3rd-edition-sep-2010.pdf)

Comment: @kiner_shah Is there a difference between the two master theorems?

Comment: They look different, although I am not sure if they really are the same and just have different representations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem from CLRS:

[image: Master theorem]

In your case, `a = 16, b = 4, f(n) = n!`

Let's calculate  [image: nlogba]. That will be `n^2`

Now, `n!` is definitely greater than [image: n^(2-e)] and `n^2`, so we will use third case of the theorem.

Let `c = 0.5`. This gives on substitution, `16 * (n / 4)! <= 0.5 * n!`

Let's put a value in `n` and check:

If `n = 100`, `16 * (100 / 4)! <= 0.5 * 100!` which gives `16 * 25! <= 0.5 * 100!`. This inequality is correct since `100!` will be way larger than `25!`. Even multiplying with `16` won't make it greater than `0.5 * 100!`.

This will be true for other larger values of `n`. So the complexity according to theorem should be [image: bigtheta(n!)]